# Google showing removed links when search for my website

Tags: html, web, search-engine

My website had a link to my profilepage, profile.html. Later I changed it to ItsMe.html. When I search for the website in the Google, its still showing profile.html. How can I change this to ItsMe.html in the google? In fact I have deleted the profil.html from my website and created the new itsme.html. I dont want to show the profile.html anywhere in google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to wait until Google crawls your site again. Once they do that, they will update their index. For a popular, continually updated site that would probably happen several times a day, but for a small personal site that doesn't often change, it will likely be a lot longer.

You can submit a request for them to recrawl your site, but no guarantees it will actually happen any quicker. ;-)

You should also set up a 301 redirect from `profile.html` to `ItsMe.html`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. My I know on average how long will google take to crawl the site and update my changes?

Comment: They don't ever officially say - checking your server logs to see when they've come in the past would probably be the most reliable indicator. But I'd say it could potentially be as long as several months, depending on the site.